# How to distinguish the screen on/off status while incoming call?

Tags: android, screen, broadcastreceiver, telephonymanager

My app uses the `TelephonyManager.ACTION_PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` for some actions. But I want a different action while the phone rang when the user was present (screen was on) and different action when the user was not present (screen was off). I tried the `isScreenOn()` method just in the beginning of `onReceive` (because when screen is off and there is incoming call, the screen stays off for a short while). No luck however - sometimes it works, sometimes not. The broadcast is asynchronous with the screen state...

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
    Boolean screenOn = pm.isScreenOn();
    Log.w(TAG, "Screen on is " + screenOn.toString());
```

How could I change my code to truly determine if the phone was sleeping when the call arrived?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I got the answer which satisfies me:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    KeyguardManager kg = (KeyguardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
    Boolean screenBlocked = !kg.inKeyguardRestrictedInputMode();
    Log.w(TAG, "Screen lock is " + screenBlocked.toString());
```

Such solution gives information if the screen is locked. And, in my case, it is enough - when screen is locked during the incoming call -  it means that there was no user.

Comment: Hi, I need your help. When screen lock is false or true i need to turn of device screen, can you help me ?