# Turn off device screen when incoming call in android

Tags: android

I want to turn off device screen when incoming call made.

I tried :

[Turn off screen on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6756768/turn-off-screen-on-android)

[How to turn screen off or send device to sleep](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8450680/how-to-turn-screen-off-or-send-device-to-sleep?lq=1)

[Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically?rq=1)

[Android - Turn off display without triggering sleep/lock screen - Turn on with Touchscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9538331/android-turn-off-display-without-triggering-sleep-lock-screen-turn-on-with-t?rq=1)

[How to distinguish the screen on/off status while incoming call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837916/how-to-distinguish-the-screen-on-off-status-while-incoming-call)

Actually I don't have Window object to turn off in my incoming call receiver.

Here is my code :

```
public class MyCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)) {
            // This code will execute when the phone has an incoming call

            // get the phone number
            String incomingNumber = intent
                    .getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
            Toast.makeText(context, "Call from:" + incomingNumber,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             // I tried code here


        } else if (intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)
                || intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE).equals(
                        TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)) {
            // This code will execute when the call is disconnected
            Toast.makeText(context, "Detected call hangup event",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    }
}
```

Can anybody help plz.

Answer (score 1):

This is at least two part probelm, first you need to detect incoming calls then blank the screen, and later I think you will want to unblank it too.

First thing you will need to do is detect incoming phone call. So I would suggest you start there. [Here is a blogpost](http://bitgriff.blogspot.com/2013/01/detecting-incoming-and-outgoing-phone.html) that explains it.

And here is a link to Android Documentation for [PhoneStateListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener.html).

You could for example blank the screen by lowering the brightness as in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10469511/turn-off-on-android-screen) question. Example code:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams layoutParam = getWindow().getAttributes();
oldBrightness = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), android.provider.Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS)/255f;
layoutParam.screenBrightness = 0; 
layoutParam.flags |= WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
getWindow().setAttributes(layoutParam);
```

Comment: I already detect incoming phone call event. But I am not getting success to turn device screen off. I update my question.

Comment: I tried this code but getting this error : The method getWindow() is undefined for the type MyCallReceiver.

Comment: Hello @mistrfu how are you?